# What are the telegram channel limitations

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

My goal is to create a mass channels fast as possible (4-5 days for 50K channel is fine), I'm about to start writing the bots for this purpose and i still not sure about limitations.

1. Waht is the maximum members that one user can invite to channel per day? 50?
2. There is a matter with the age of the invited members (of course they would be fake and not real legit accounts)
3. What do i need to create a telegram user creator bot ?
4. Any other limitations which i have to be aware of i'm mising?

I was trying to search all over the internet include chatGPT some info about channel limitations and it seems like there is no straightforward answer for that

Answer (score 1):

You can check telegram channel limitations and properties by this [link](https://telegram.org/faq_channels).

According to Telegram's documentation

> you may invite the first 200 subscribers to your channel. Once the subscriber count reaches 200, the channel is on its own. If it's a public channel, it will have a username and a telegram.me/ link (e.g. t.me/telegram) – you can post this link on social networks, advertise it in magazines, or tattoo it on your back. If you have a private channel, you can send an invite link to your friends.